# Searching for an unordered triple in a list of triples

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, searching

I have a list of triples which looks like this

```
T = {{7, 1, 2}, {7, 2, 3}, {7, 3, 8}, {7, 1, 6}};
```

(I have suppressed a few triples for clarity. My real list is larger.)

The problem is that

```
MemberQ[T, {7, 1, 2}]
```

returns `True`, but

```
MemberQ[T, {7, 2, 1}]`
```

returns `False`.

It is a known fact that a list is treated as an ordered list, not as a  set, by Mathematica. But in my specific application, all I want to distinguish between are triples like `{7, 1, 2}` and `{7, 3, 8}`. But `{7, 1, 2}` and `{7, 2, 1}` are to be treated as identical.

How do I achieve this in Mathematica?

Comment: You could `Sort` subsets first....

Comment: Do you have to apply the `MemberQ` check often?

Comment: Yes, but Sort seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be a case for [OrderlessPatternSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderlessPatternSequence.html)

```
tT = {{7, 1, 2}, {7, 2, 3}, {7, 3, 8}, {7, 1, 6}};

MemberQ[tT, {OrderlessPatternSequence[1, 2, 7]}]
```

> True

Or define a function to wrap the second argument of `MemberQ`:

```
foo = {OrderlessPatternSequence @@ ##}&;

MemberQ[tT, foo @ {1,2,7}]
```

> True

```
MemberQ[tT, foo @ #] & /@ {{1, 2, 7}, {3, 8, 7},{1, 2, 3}}
```

> {True,True,False}

Comment: Thanks for your answer @kglr.

Comment: @leastaction, my pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

If the order will never matter for your lists, you can use an [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) head rather than list.

I use `slist` (sorted list) :

```
ClearAll[slist]    
SetAttributes[slist, Orderless]
```

Then Mathematica will automatically sort any input given to `slist` :

```
slistT = slist @@@ T
```

> ```
> {slist[1, 2, 7], slist[2, 3, 7], slist[3, 7, 8], slist[1, 6, 7]}
> ```

This is the way Mathematica handles functions like `Plus` or `Times` which don't care about the order of their elements.

In your case, you can do

```
 MemberQ[slistT, slist[7, 1, 2] ]  (* True *)
 MemberQ[slistT, slist[7, 2, 1] ]  (* True *)
```

Comment: Note that this way, the arrays get unpacked which slows things down. Mapping `Sort` over the list is faster...

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround

```
Xor @@ Sequence[MemberQ[T, #] & /@ Permutations[{7, 2, 1}]]

(*    True    *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Akku14

Answer (score 2):

If you have to perform many checks of this kind, it might justify the overhead to create a lookup table in form of an `Association`.

The first thing here is a listable variant of `Sort` that also employs parallelization.

```
sort = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
   Sort[list],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True
   ];
```

This will be the replacement for `MemberQ`. Note that we

```
memberQ[S_Association, R_?MatrixQ] := Unitize[Lookup[S, sort@R, 0]];
memberQ[S_Association, R_?VectorQ] := Unitize[Lookup[S, sort[{R}], 0]][[1]];
```

Some not so big test data...

```
n = 2000;
m = 30;
d = 3;
T = DeleteDuplicates[sort@RandomInteger[{1, m}, {n, d}]];
R = RandomInteger[{1, m}, {n, d}];
```

Now, we create the lookup table `S` for `T`:

```
S = AssociationThread[sort@T, Range[Length[T]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.002173

And this is how our new `memberQ` compares to `MemberQ` in conjunction with `Sort`:

```
a = Boole[MemberQ[T, Sort[#]] & /@ R]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = memberQ[S, R]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b
```

> 0.496145
>
> 0.001229
>
> True

This will also work well for longer lists. For lists of length `d=2`, it is more efficient to use a `SparseArray` as lookup table. For short lists of given length `d`, this can be further improved by writing specialized and compiled sorting routines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Henrik Schumacher!

Comment: @leastaction You're welcome!